# Two steps forward and one step back

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

Let's say I'm ten steps away from my destination. I walk there following the old saying, "Two steps forward and one step back". I take two steps forward, one back, until I'm standing exactly on my destination. (This might involve stepping past my destination, and returning to it). How many steps did I walk?

Of course, I might not be 10 steps away. I might be 11 steps away, or 100.
I could measure ten paces, and keep walking back and forth to solve the problem, or... I could write some code!

- Write a function to work out how many steps it takes to get N steps away, in the sequence: two steps forward, one step back.
- Assume you've started at step 0. Count the "two steps forward" as two steps, not one.
- Assume all steps are a uniform length.
- It should return the number of steps first taken when you reach that space. (For instance, 10 steps away takes 26 steps, but you'd hit it again at step 30). We're interested in the 26.
- Use any language you like.
- It should accept any positive integer as input. This represents the target step.
- Smallest number of bytes win.

Example:

I want to get 5 steps away:

```
| | | | | | <- I'm at step 0, not yet on the grid.
| |X| | | | <- I take two steps forward, I'm on step 2: the count is 2
|X| | | | | <- I take one step back, I'm on step 1: the count is 3
| | |X| | | <- I take two steps forward, I'm on step 3: the count is 5
| |X| | | | <- I take one step back, I'm on step 2 again: the count is 6
| | | |X| | <- I take two steps forward, I'm on step 4: the count is 8
| | |X| | | <- I take one step back, I'm on step 3 again: the count is 9
| | | | |X| <- I take two steps forward, I'm on step 5: the count is 11
```

In this case, the result of the function would be 11.

Example results:

```
1      =>  3
5      =>  11
9      =>  23
10     =>  26
11     =>  29
100    =>  296
1000   =>  2996
10000  =>  29996
100000 =>  299996
```

Have fun, golfers!

Comment: Hmm ... this feels very familiar.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/130290/the-snail-in-the-well)

Comment: @Rod Hooray! I got away with it! ;)

Comment: Yep, that looks like the one I was thinking of, @Rod.

Comment: @Shaggy Rod changed his comment a little. The earlier one noted that the snails/wells question is asking for the number of iterations, but this is asking for the distance covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Adnan*

```
3+23
```

*Not to be confused with `23+3`*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/99Y28j4////lv91/QE)

**How?**

```
      implicitly push a(n-1)
3     push 3
 +    sum and implicitly print
  2   a(2) = 2
   3  a(1) = 3
```

Comment: You can leave out the `b`.

Comment: I think you meant to multiply with 3, not add it.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The program computes **a(n)** as **a(n-1)+3**.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda n:3*n-1%n*4
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk/LWNdQNU/L5H9afpFCnkJmnoKhjoKpjoKljoKhARAbgmgDMAElYZSBlUJBUWZeiYJGno5CmkaepuZ/AA)

I picked this trick up [from xnor](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?multiply+SI+units/xnor_1521614421&py) just a few days ago…!

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*3-4*(n>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcQ7CoAwEAXAq2wXPxvI@ikU9CQWUSQo6FNCGk8fFS1mzissB4rouiFu4z7NI6FFVuoqS9BLGt3hCbSChGtuWAyLPJvX179pT78ikIXN1RAUK90rdgnSeAM)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 17 bytes

```python
lambda n:n-3%~n*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk/XWLUuTwsoml@kkKeQmadgqKNgqqNgqaNgaADEhiDaAExASRhlYKVQUJSZV6KgkaejkKaRp6n5HwA)

I found the expression by brute-force search. It effectively computes `n+2*abs(n-2)`.

Answer (score 9):

## Polyglot: Java 8 / JavaScript / C# .NET, <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```java
n->3*n-1%n*4
```

[Try it online (Java 8).](https://tio.run/##jY3NCoJAFIX3PsXdBKOgOFSLkHqD3LiMFrfRYvy5ijMKET77NJrbGDcH7vk@zi1xxLDMKyNqVAquKOnjAUjSRf9EUUA6n0sBgs1JfmKbybOhNGopIAWCMxgKL/uAQr6j4GCSmXfDo7Z81cZW5tDYByzTvaTX7Q7o/9azt9JFE7WDjjqLdE2MIsG4v/z6y48OfnJwHrsE7lyI3cYWZZOzSpM3mS8)

```java
n=>3*n-1%n*4
```

[Try it online (JavaScript).](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1s5YK0/XUDVPy@R/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahpqY1F6qQKaaQJaaQoQEWMUNs6gywCuIQxSUMEv8PAA)
[Try it online (C# .NET)](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv2fnJNYXKzgW82loFBQmpSTmaxQXJJYAqTK8jNTFHwTM/M0NEGSCgrBlcUlqbl6bqV5yTaZeSU6CkDCTiFNwfZ/nq2dsVaerqFqnpbJf2tkxc75ecX5Oal64UWZJak@mXmpGmkahpqaBNWYEqHGkgg1hgbEKDIkyiQD4lQRq4xodVCFtVy1/wE).

Port of [*@Lynn*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160337/52210), so make sure to upvote his/her answer.

---

***Old answer:***

## Polyglot: Java 8 / JavaScript / C# .NET, <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```java
n->n<2?3:n*3-4
```

[Try it online (Java 8).](https://tio.run/##jY27DoJAEEV7vmLKxQQCooXi4wukoTQW44JmEQbCLiTG8O3rgrRmaW4y95zcKbBHr8hempcoJVxQ0McBEKTy9oE8h2Q8pwI4G5Pc2DSDY0IqVIJDAgRH0OSd6LA@R3taRd5Gx6PRdPfSGLPY1yKDyrxgqWoFPa83QPe3n76lyiu/7pTfGKRKYuRzFrrTt798a@E7Cw8DmxBaFwK7sURZ5MzS4Az6Cw)

```java
n=>n<2?3:n*3-4
```

[Try it online (JavaScript).](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7Pxsje2CpPy1jX5H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqGmpjUXqpApppAlppChARYxQ2zqDLAK4hDFJQwS/w8A)
[Try it online (C# .NET)](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv2fnJNYXKzgW82loFBQmpSTmaxQXJJYAqTK8jNTFHwTM/M0NEGSCgrBlcUlqbl6bqV5yTaZeSU6CkDCTiFNwfZ/nq1dno2RvbFVnpaxrsl/a2Tlzvl5xfk5qXrhRZklqT6ZeakaaRqGmpoE1ZgSocaSCDWGBsQoMiTKJAPiVBGrjGh1UIW1XLX/AQ).

**Explanation:**

```java
n->       // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  n<2?    //  If the input is 1:
   3      //   Return 3
  :       //  Else:
   n*3-4  //   Return the input multiplied by 3, and subtract 4
```

Comment: JavaScript polyglot, if you use a fat arrow.

Comment: @Shaggy Added, as well as C# .NET :) Although `n=>(--n*3||4)-1` is also possible in JavaScript (also 14 bytes).

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
3*s≠i4-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fWKv4UeeCTBPd//8NAQ)

-1 byte thanks to Emigna !

Comment: `3*s≠i4-` saves a byte

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

```r
N=scan();3*N-4*(N>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/38@2ODkxT0PT2ljLT9dES8PPzlDzv6GBgcF/AA)

Didn't notice the pattern until after I had implemented my less elegant solution.

Comment: Congrats on 10k BTW!

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks! I think my one-year anniversary on the site was a couple days ago, so it's been a good week for me, PPCG-wise.

Comment: @Giuseppe I know the feeling: 20k last week, as well as 2nd year anniversary. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 5 bytes

```
¹y4-3
```

Explanation:

```
    3  defines f(1) = 3
¹y4-   defines f(n) as:
¹      push input
 y     triple
  4-   subtract four
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@///QzkoTXeP///@b/tf1BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 15 bytes

```hs
f 1=3
f n=3*n-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03B0NaYK00hz9ZYK0/X5H9uYmaegq1CbmKBr4JGQVFmXomCnkKapoKKQrShjoKpjoKljoKhARAbgmgDMAElYZRB7H8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Standard ML](http://www.mlton.org/), 16 bytes

```ml
fn 1=>3|n=>3*n-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@1@WmKOQpmCr8D8tT8HQ1s64Jg9IaOXpmvy3VigoyswrUdAILgHS6XrJ@XnJiSXhmSUZCkoxeUoKGrmJBQoannkleiX5ECUK@QppmgrRhjoKpjoKljoKhgZAbAiiDcAElIRRBrGamtb/AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 27 bytes

```
	dot D
D
	
	d d
	d d
d
	dip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/58zJb9EwYXLhYuTizNFIQVCgKjMgv///xsagAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
++_>¡4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19bO97u0EKT////GxqAAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
3∘×-4×1∘<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wTjRx0zDk/XNTk83RDIsgEKHlrxqHezoQEA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 21 bytes

```
1*3.
X*Y:-Y is 3*X-4.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/31DLWI8rQivSSjdSIbNYwVgrQtdEDyhsYGCgFaEHAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

Uses the `3*n-4*(n>1)` formula. Multiply input by 3 (`3*`), push input again (`G`) and decrement it (`q`). If the result is not zero (`?`) then subtract 4 from the result (`4-`).

```
3*Gq?4-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/31jLvdDeRPf/f0MDIAAA)

Comment: 6 bytes porting Dennis' Jelly answer `2-|EG+`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ạ2Ḥ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroVGD3cs0f5/dM/hdvf//w11FEx1FCx1FAwNgNgQRBuACSgJowwA)

#### How it works

```
ạ2Ḥ+  Main link. Argument: n

ạ2    Absolute difference with 2; yield |n-2|.
  Ḥ   Unhalve/double; yield 2|n-2|.
   +  Add; yield 2|n-2|+n.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Jo King*

```
3*:3)4*-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31jLyljTREs37////7plCoYGBgYA)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31jLyljTREs37////7plCoYGBgYA "><> – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing: Don't kow how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 20 bytes

```c
f(n){n=3*n-4*!!~-n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs/WWCtP10RLUbFON8@69r@@PqqwRp6NkaZ1LRe6OEQ5QjjPztAeLGUFJIESXLmJmXkaWZrVaflFGlm2BtZZNoYGBtaaBUWZeSVpGkqqKTpKOmka2tpZmkDj/wMA)

Comment: Alternative with the same byte-count: `f(n){n=n<2?3:n*3-4;}`

Comment: Another alternative with the same byte count: `f(n){n=n*3-4*(n>1);}`

Answer (score 3):

## [MachineCode](https://github.com/aaronryank/MachineCode) on x86_64, <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
8d47fe9931d029d08d0447c3
```

Requires the `i` flag for integer output; input is taken via manually appending to the code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y01MzsjMS03OT0n9/98ixcQ8LdXS0tgwxcDIMsXAIsXAxMQ82fi/ocH//5kA)

---

I went through these 4 different C functions to find the 24-byte MachineCode program:

- `n+2*abs(n-2)` = `8d47fe9931d029d08d0447c3` (24 bytes)
- `3*n-4*!!~-n` = `8d047f31d2ffcf0f95c2c1e20229d0c3` (32 bytes)
- `n*3-4*(n>1)` = `31d283ff028d047f0f9dc2c1e20229d0c3` (34 bytes)
- `n<2?3:n*3-4` = `83ff01b8030000007e068d047f83e804c3` (34 bytes)

Comment: so what exactly is this language?

Comment: @qwr Check out the README in the repository for a simple description.

Answer (score 2):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 54 bytes

```
3.6010160303604047002020003100000180010202046000095024
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYgxDoAwDAP3vCIzEshpTCgDUh/OxMdCCrask4@ZvgUMFnB4gOABtCrghhnrtU8x5j93NGYOkaGXBuW5i9a7BHVR11X5ixc)

If you question the input method, please visit first the [numerical input and output may be given as a character code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4719/65326) meta post.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Because the answer appears to be one quarter, which isn't a valid result. As far as I can tell, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AJFaraday it uses byte input and output, which is valid by meta consensus. see the explanation inside the input section

Comment: Any resources on how to interpret the result? Or the input?

Comment: @AJFaraday the char code of the result is the answer. I've edited the question to include the relevant meta post. `4` has only char input.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 7 bytes

A port of Lynn's Python solution.

```
*3É%U*4
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=KjPJJVUqNA==&input=OA==)

---

### Alternative

This was a fun alternative to the closed formula solutions that is, unfortunately, a byte longer:

```
_+3}gN³²
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=XyszfWdOs7I=&input=OA==)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 8 bytes

```
3Ans-4(Ans>1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Uses the abs-method from [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160350/47066)

```
2α·+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVln53@jcxkPbtf9XKh3er6Brp3B4v5LOf0MuUy5LLkMDLkNDIGkAwhACShoAAA)

**Explanation**

```
2α      # abs(input, 2)
  ·     # multiply by 2
   +    # add input
```

Answer (score 2):

## 65816 machine code, 22 bytes

I could have made this 65C02 machine code easily for 3 bytes less, but didn't, since the register size on the 65C02 is 8-bit instead of 16-bit. It would work, but it's boring because you can only use really low numbers ;-)

xxd dump:

```
00000000: 7aa9 0000 aa89 0100 d004 8888 e824 c8e8  z............$..
00000010: 1ac0 0000 d0ef                           ......
```

disassembly / code explanation:

```
; target is on the stack
  ply              7A                  ; pull target from stack
  lda #$0000       A9 00 00            ; set loop counter to 0
  tax              AA                  ; set step counter to 0
loop:
  bit #$0001       89 01 00            ; sets Z if loop counter is even
  bne odd          D0 04               ; if Z is not set, jump to 'odd'
  dey              88                  ; decrement target twice
  dey              88
  inx              E8                  ; increment step counter
  .byte $24        24                  ; BIT $xx opcode, effectively skips the next byte
odd:
  iny              C8                  ; increment target

  inx              E8                  ; increment step counter
  inc a            1A                  ; increment loop counter

  cpy #$0000       C0 00 00            ; sets zero flag, can be optimized maybe?
  bne loop         D0 EF               ; if Y is non-zero, loop

; result is in register X
```

Testing it out on a 65816-compatible emulator:

[image: testing]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://tio.run/#python3), 48 bytes

```
def a(x):
    if x!=1:
        return((3*x)-4)
    return(3)
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFRo0LTioszM02hQtHWEMjiLEotKS3K09Aw1qrQ1DXR5IIJGGv@LyjKzCvRSNQw1NTkgrFNkdiWSGxDA2SOIYoMUOo/AA)

Comment: Nice work. You might want to put some code in the “Footer” section, too. That way you can test your function without padding out your golf entry...

Comment: @AJFaraday The footer of my post or of my code?

Comment: On Try It Online; you can add a footer which runs with your code but doesn’t count towards the byte length. Then the output will show your code at work.

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6faBvzPycxNyklUaHCKtpYR8NYq0JT1yQ2usLOMPZ/QVFmXolGooahpiYXjG2KxLZEYhsaIHMMUWSAUv8B "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing Do you know of a good guide to lambda functions in Python? I really don't understand how the syntax works.

Comment: The variables directly after the lambda are equivalent to def e.g. `a=lambda x,y` is the same as `def a(x,y)`. Imagine there's also a `return` directly after the `:`, and other than that it's basically the same. `def a(x,y): return x+y` is the same as `a=lambda x,y: x+y`

Comment: How do the brackets work? Are they if statement equivalents? If not, can you do ifs and loops in a lambda function?

Comment: It's a list of two elements, where the conditional returns True/False which is equivalent to 1/0, deciding which element is returned. A less golfier, but more readable construction is to use an inline if e.g. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6faBvzPycxNyklUaHCylghM02hwsZIITWnOFXBWKtC1@R/QVFmXolGooahpiYXjG2KxLZEYhsaIHMMUWSAUv8B "Python 3 – Try It Online"). If you want to check out more python golfing tips, check out [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

**SHELL** , **28 Bytes**

```
F(){ bc<<<$1*3-$(($1>1))*4;}
```

Tests :

```
F 1
3

F 2
2

F 3
5

F 4
8

F5
11

F 11
29

F 100
296

F 100000
299996
```

Explanation :

The formula is :

```
if n == 1  ==> F(1) = 3
else F(n) = 3*n - 4
```

following the sequence of 3 steps  "Two steps forward and one step back", we will have the arithmetic series :

```
 +2  2 => 2  ( or 6 )
 -1  1 => 3
 -----------
 +2  3 => 5  ( or 9 )
 -1  2 => 6
 -----------
 +2  4 => 8  ( or 12 )
 -1  3 => 9
 -----------
 +2  5 => 11 ( or 15 )
 -1  4 => 12
 -----------
 +2  6 => 14 ( or 18 )
 -1  5 => 15 
 -----------
 +2  7 => 17 ( or 21 )
 -1  6 => 18
```

At the minimum, or first coincidence :

```
 1 => 3
 2 => 2
 3 => 5
 4 => 8
 5 => 11
 6 => 14
```

in one formula :

```
F(n) = 3*n - 4(n>1)     with n>1 is 1 or 0 (if n==1)
```

Comment: please describe which shell this is

Comment: tested on Cygwin ( CYGWIN_NT-10.0 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin)

Comment: can you write it in bc directly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bc, but since the argument of the function ($1) is used several times and some shell-specific stuff (arithmetic expansion, `$((…))`) is done, probably not.

Comment: `F(){bc<<<$1*3-$(($1>1))*4}` works in zsh though and removes 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
3&*-4*1&<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jdW0dE20DNVs/mtycaUmZ@QraNhZZeoZGWjq6KUpQJhc/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 15 bytes

```matlab
@(n)3*n-4*(n>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0/TWCtP10RLI8/OUPN/moaBlaGB5n8A)

Kind of surprised there isn't already a MATLAB answer. Same algorithm of `3*n-4` if greater than 1, or `3*n` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 38 bytes

```
({<([()()]{})>()(){(<((){})>)()}{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6PaRiNaQ1NDM7a6VtMOxKjWsNEAkkAekFNbXQtEmv//GxoYGAAA)

The first answer I see to calculate the answer by stepping back and forth.

```
({ while not at 0
  <([()()]{})>()() take two steps forward, counting 2 steps
  {(<((){})>)()}{} take one step back, if not at 0, and add 1 step
}{}) remove the 0 and push step sum
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `d`, 7 bytes

```
♦óÖ╣░Θ$
```

### Explanation

```
3*1a<4*-
```

Evaluates `(a*3)-4*(a>1)`.

### Another possible alternative

```
3*1am4*-
```

Evaluates `(a*3)-4*(1%a)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```ruby
->n{3*n-1%n*4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2lgrT9dQNU/LpPZ/tKGOqY6ljqGBjqEhkDQAYQgBJQ1i9VITkzMUqmtKahQKSkuKFZSUq0tqFWztFJSr06JLYmuVav8DAA)

Uses the `1%1==0` trick as seen in other answers here.